# Can't plug fuse into Silverado 2018 panel

Tags: fuse-panel

I have a hardwire kit for my dashcam, but I can't get it to plug into any of the available circuits. The only slot that seems to fit is 21 but the fuse won't actually plug into anything, it just sits loosely. I'm not sure where else to put this.

The hardwire kit I have is this: Rexing Mini-USB Hardwire Kit for V1, V1P, V1 3rd Gen Dash Cams [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LXC2329/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_TYxlCbNYJ701H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LXC2329)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to plug that adaptor fuse into a slot that already has a fuse using a circuit with the functionality you need, ie always on, acc on or ignition on.

That adaptor fuse replaces the existing fuse, so remove the old one and fit the adaptor fuse in its place.

So, 27 theft may be always on

31 may be acc, and

23 ignition

Assuming from the poor text given in the legends - you will need to test...

Edit: Just to show you a diagram for using a relay:
[image]

Comment: If I replace an existing fuse, will it disable whatever was already running there? Does the adapter I have just pull extra power from the circuit for the camera, leaving the other stuff untouched?

Comment: No, it will not disable the original circuit, it just pulls power for the camera and the other things continue...

Comment: Fuse 24 (Spare) looks to be the optimal fuse to use. The adapter fuse appears to be a 15A ATO fuse. There's only two of them in the fuse panel (22 & 24). If 24 is a spare (as in I don't have a clue why it's there then) and provides power, but as the name implies isn't really used, this would be perfect spot for it as it would not interfere with anything else, as well as it won't overload the circuit.

Comment: My plug won't fit into anything except the empty #21 and the filled #13 and #14, which are labeled as 2amp. I assume putting a 15amp fuse there wouldn't be safe? #21 is empty

Comment: The others that you mentioned are 3 prong outlets.

Comment: It looks like the kit I have uses a mini fuse, but my Silverado panel uses micros. Is there a mini to micro adapter I can get maybe?

Comment: @MrDuk I would trace one of the spare wires leading to the fuse box and use that - usually the empty positions don't have terminals... The other option would be to use that supply to trigger a relay if you are worried about the current drawn by the camera.

Comment: That all sounds a bit more advanced than my limited experience allows. If I can't get an adapter, I guess I'll have to take this to a service center :(

Comment: @MrDuk have a look round for an autoelectrician or vehicle electrician - a good one will do that in a half-hour... and know exactly what they are looking for so peace of mind.

Comment: @MrDuk just updated my post with a diagram that may help you.